# On click remove div with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services

If i click on X it will delete div:

```js
$('#close').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('div').remove();
})
```

```html
<div class="single_add">

    <i id="close" class="fa fa-times-circle">X</i>

    ads

</div>
```

The code working in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Ny346/161/

But it's not working when I upload it on my server

http://www.bohgames.com/js.html

What is the problem ?

Comment: you did not include jquery script check console for error it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: Yes @guradio is right. This error is typical of a non included jQuery library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="single_add">

<i id="close" class="fa fa-times-circle" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';">X</i>

ads

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not include jquery script check console for error it says 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Include jquery script and it will be ok

Answer (score 0):

You have not included jQuery library.
Add this to you page head or bottom

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had not included JQuery Script,

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```